# Eigen crashes when pushing matrix to vector

Tags: eigen3

When compiling with `marhc=native`, this code gives segfault:

```
// Compute all transformations matrices and put into a vector
std::vector<mu::MF4> smpl::get_all_transformations(const mu::MFX &new_joints, const mu::MFX &theta)
{
    std::vector<mu::MF4> G_vec;
    mu::MFX theta_star = mu::MFX::Zero(theta.rows(), theta.cols());
    for (auto k = 0; k < mu::NBRJOINTS; ++k)
    {
        mu::MF4 G_ = get_rigid_tr(theta, new_joints, k);
        mu::MF4 G_star = get_rigid_tr(theta_star, get_J(), k);
        mu::MF4 tmp = G_*G_star.inverse();
        std::cout<<"Before crash "<<std::endl;
        getchar();
        G_vec.push_back(tmp);
        std::cout<<"After crash"<<std::endl;
    }
    return G_vec;
}
```

`mu::MFX/4` are typedefs for `Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>` or `Eigen::Matrix4f`.

When I run this code I get the output

```
Before crash 

After crash
Before crash 

Segmentation fault
```

when I compile with `march=native`. When I compile without it, then it runs perfectly. What can the problem be? My colleague can run it with `march-native` as I understood it.

I am using Eigen from the package manager on Ubuntu 18.04 and I have the following flags:

```
message(STATUS "Found Eigen headers in: ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR}")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -lrt -std=c++17 -O3 -fopenmp -march=native")
```

EDIT:

I have not been able to reproduce it, but when I renamed all `std::vector::mu::MF4> to std::vector<mu::MF4,Eigen::aligned_allocator<mu::MF4> >` the crash disappeared. Seems a bit random that it fails on my big project but it works on a small example.

Comment: What chip are you targeting, what chip is your colleague targeting? Or are you compiling and running the binary on his computer? Also, if you can supply a [MCVE], it would help others help you.

Comment: Does `${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}` contain `-DNDEBUG`? (e.g, are you in any kind of cmake-release mode). Please check this page: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html

Comment: The `{CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}` are as in the question, no `-DNDEBUG`. I have not specified any Release or Debug mode. 

Could not create a failing minimal example, but adding some `Eigen::Align` made it work.